# How to execute a function only when clicking outside of a div when the function requires a key value from ng-repeat?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a div with an input inside. Something similar to this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in someJSON">
    <div>
        Some content
    </div>
    <form>
        <input ng-focus="action(key)"> 
    </form>
</div>
```

*What I'm trying to accomplish*: I want to perform an action when the input gets focused on and I want to later execute reverseAction(key) if a click occurs outside of the PARENT div.

The `reverseAction()` requires the key so I can't put an `ng-click` on the body tag to reverse the action. `ng-blur` doesn't help me too much (at least not the way I've been using it) as it will perform the action even if I click within the div.

Any ideas?

Comment: use a directive to add / remove the click handler on document